# JAX-WS Client Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

I'm being forced to remove CXF from my web service. To remove any dependencies on the authentication, I had setup an HttpAuthSupplier class to handle basic authentication.

```
public class ExchangeAuthSupplier implements HttpAuthSupplier{
       @Override
       public boolean requiresRequestCaching() {
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public String getAuthorization(AuthorizationPolicy authPolicy, URL url, Message message, String fullHeader) {
           // Lookup authentication information and return appropriate header
       }

}
```

What I'm trying to figure out how I can do something similar using regular JAX-WS API and Spring...

Comment: Are you allowed to use Spring WS?

Comment: Yes I am... I'm thinking the best way right now is to implement a soap handler...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question... I decided to go with using Handlers. So I created a SOAPHandler similar to ExchangeAuthSupplier above:

```
public class MyAuthenticationHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        final Boolean outInd = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outInd.booleanValue()) {
            try {
                UserNamePasswordPair userNamePasswordPair = getAuthorization(); // Method to retrieve credentials from somewhere

                context.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, userNamePasswordPair.getUsername());
                context.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, userNamePasswordPair.getPassword());

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        logger.error("error occurred when getting auth.");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        logger.debug("closing handler for auth...");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Created a HandlerResolver to add the resolvers to a chain:

```
public class MyHandlerResolver implements HandlerResolver {
    private List<Handler> chain;

    public MyHandlerResolver() {
        chain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        chain.add(new MyAuthenticationHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        return chain;
    }
}
```

And then in Spring, just hooked it all up like this:

```
<bean id="myJAXWSClient" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="Interface to implement"/>
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:/wsdl/theWsdl.wsdl"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="namespace"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="ServiceName"/>
    <property name="endpointAddress" value="/endpoint"/>
    <property name="handlerResolver" ref="myHandlerResolver"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myHandlerResolver" class="com.mystuff.ExchangeHandlerResolver"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

For Basic auth and Spring's JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean you can simply use:

```
<bean id="myJAXWSClient" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="Interface to implement"/>
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="classpath:/wsdl/theWsdl.wsdl"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri" value="namespace"/>
    <property name="serviceName" value="ServiceName"/>
    <property name="endpointAddress" value="/endpoint"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to kaczors answer for Basic authentication with Spring's JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean,
if the wsdl or xsd is not in the classpath and need to be accessed from an url which requires basic authentication, create a custom JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean which will enable WSDL url http basic authentication.

public class CustomJaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean extends JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean {

```
@Override
public Service createJaxWsService() {

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    getUsername(),
                    getPassword().toCharArray());
        }
    });
    return super.createJaxWsService();
}
```

Thanks to sundaramss of [spring forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/other-spring-related/remoting/53425-spring-2-5-5-and-jax-ws-http-authentication)

Comment: Warning: Authenticator.setDefault is static, and thus if two requests are made at the same time, authentication from one request will leak into the other request. If you're going to use it at all, you should make a custom Authenticator which uses ThreadLocal to ensure each thread uses isolated information, but generally speaking, I'd say it's safer to avoid it.